# Divs do not auto size

Tags: html, css

I have an MVC web site and the Div's are not auto-sizing

I've set overflow to auto, I've set a minimum height

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="jetdocs-header">
        <img src="~/Content/images/logo_header.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="content-section">
        <div class="content-menu">

        </div>
        <div class="content-body">
            <div style="width: 900px; height: 30px;">

            </div>
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is the CSS

```
.content-wrapper {
    background-image: url('images/top.gif');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    width: 1155px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px auto 0 auto;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
    min-height: 600px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.content-section {
    top: 5px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    overflow: auto;
}

.content-menu {
    position: relative;
    width: 140px;
    min-height: 700px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: silver;
    float: left;
    overflow: auto;
}

.content-body {
    position: relative;
    width: 1000px;
    float: left;
    left: 2px;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

The Content-Menu should auto-size to the same height as the content-section. and both should cause the content-wrapper to auto-size to match the height of the largest of the two...

Comment: If you specify hardcoded width and overflow:auto, it wont auto resize. Try percentages. Also, try with just one div and play around in a jsfiddle.

Comment: You can get divs to behave any way you want. It is just a matter of getting the correct css. To many, this may seem trivial but I have been in your situation. :) Try to just get one div working. Or edit your question and state the behaviour you need and you will get some good feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think this c# related, but have you tried setting the height of the parent divs? I think even if you specify min-height, it still needs height for the overflow to work correct.

Comment: The "Code Behind" is c# which is why I included that Tag. I did and have. my biggest issue with this is the menu  does not auto size greater than the min-height. I'm the first to admit I'm a CSS novice, I can do the basics but spend a lot of time setting top = negative values when I don't  understand why thigns dont line up

Answer (score 0):

I think use should use the css3 flexbox properties on the '.content-section'.

```
.content-section
{
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
}
.content-body
{
    min-height: 600px;
}
```

The Content-Menu will get the size of the Content-Body (or invers if the Content-Menu is higher), and the Content-Section will auto-size to match the height of the childs. More info about `align-items` here:  https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: that worked it repositioned  some items on the page, I simply changed the top values on the 6 items and its fine now thanks..